# Struct declaration error in C

Tags: c, struct

ive got a struct problem it returns:

```
cd.h:15: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
```

its probably something simple ...

```
  struct cd {
        char titel[32];
        char artiest[32];
        int speelduur;  

    };

    typedef struct cd CD;
    struct cdlijst{ 
        CD *item;
        struct cdlijst *next;
    }


    typedef struct cdlijst CDLijst;
```

Comment: OMG found it, it was a missing ; :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you need a semicolon after the second struct declaration, like this:

```
struct cdlijst{ 
    CD *item;
    struct cdlijst *next;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Some otherwise incomprehensible error messages (including this one) are due to things as simple as missing semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you missed a semi-colon at the end of declaration of struct cdlijst, add a semi-colon will fixes the problem.

By the way, I would like to recommand [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) for syntax correcting, since it will give much better explanations on compiling errors. Here is an article comparing gcc and Clang on error recovery messages: http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/amazing-feats-of-clang-error-recovery.html.